# A question on symmetric functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, symmetric-polynomials

Let $0 \leq m \leq n$ be integers. The group $S_n$ of permutations acts on the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ by permuting the coordinates, with fixed subring $\mathbb{Z}[\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n]$, where the $\sigma_j$'s are the elementary symmetric functions.

Let $H$ be the stabilizer of $P = \prod_{j=m+1}^n X_j^m$, which is the subgroup of permutations leaving $[m+1,n]$ globally invariant, and consider the expansion
$$
\prod_{\sigma \in S_n/H} (T - {}^{\sigma} P) = T^{\binom{n}{m}} + a_1 T^{\binom{n}{m} - 1} + a_2 T^{\binom{n}{m}-2} + \dots +a_{\binom{n}{m}}.
$$
All $a_j$'s are fixed by $S_n$, hence can be written as $a_j = A_j(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n)$, for a unique polynomial $A_j$.

> > Is it always true that the degree of $A_j$ is at most $jm$ ?

Note that if we give weight $j$ to $\sigma_j$, then $A_j$ is easily seen to have degree $jm(n-m)$, but here I'm asking for the degree of $A_j$ where we give weight $1$ to $\sigma_j$.

The answer is "yes" (and easy) when $m=0,1,n-1,n$. I also checked the case $m=2,n=4$, so that one can assume $n \geq 5$. I have strong reasons to believe, or at least to expect, that the result is true in general.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then $a_j $ is $\pm $ the sum of all possible products of $j $ distinct $n-m $-element subsets of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n $. This is a symmetric polynomial of degree at most $j\left(n-m\right) $, so the degree of $A_j $ is also at most $j\left(n-m\right) $ (by a standard claim in the fundamental theorem on elementary symmetric polynomials).

Comment: But in $P$, the $X_j$'s are raised to the power $m$...

Comment: Oh, I see. OK, let me first try to generalize your question. I let $e_0, e_1, e_2, \ldots$ be the elementary symmetric functions in countably many indeterminates $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$. (These are symmetric functions -- thus, power series, not polynomials -- but I can of course evaluate them at finitely many values.) I claim that $e_j\left(\left(x_{i_1}^d x_{i_2}^d \cdots x_{i_k}^d\right)_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k}\right)$ can be written as a polynomial of degree $\leq jd$ in $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots$ for any $j$, $d$ and $k$. (Here, ...

Comment: ... I use the notation $e_j\left(\mathfrak{f}\right)$ for the result of evaluating the symmetric function $e_j$ at the entries of a finite family $\mathfrak{f}$ of elements of a commutative ring.) Your question follows from my claim when we set $d = m$ and $k = n-m$ and set all $x_i$ with $i > n$ to zero. So it remains to prove my claim. The first step is to reduce it to the case when the ground ring is $\mathbb{Q}$: Indeed, it is clear that $e_j\left(\left(x_{i_1}^d x_{i_2}^d \cdots x_{i_k}^d\right)_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k}\right)$ can be written as a ...

Comment: ... polynomial in $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots$; the degree of this polynomial surely does not change when we pass from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Now that we are over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can use Newton's formulas to reduce the problem to the following one: Show that $p_j\left(\left(x_{i_1}^d x_{i_2}^d \cdots x_{i_k}^d\right)_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k}\right)$ can be written as a polynomial of degree $\leq jd$ in $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots$, where $p_j$ is the $j$-th power-sum symmetric function. This is a lot simpler, ...

Comment: ... since $p_j\left(\left(x_{i_1}^d x_{i_2}^d \cdots x_{i_k}^d\right)_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k}\right) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} x_{i_1}^{e} x_{i_2}^{e} \cdots x_{i_k}^{e}$, where $e = jd$. Now, let $\lambda$ be the partition $\left(e,e,\ldots,e\right)$ with a total of $k$ entries. Then, $p_j\left(\left(x_{i_1}^d x_{i_2}^d \cdots x_{i_k}^d\right)_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k}\right) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} x_{i_1}^{e} x_{i_2}^{e} \cdots x_{i_k}^{e} = m_\lambda$, where $m_\lambda$ is the $\lambda$-th monomial symmetric function. So ...

Comment: ... we have to prove that $m_\lambda$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq e$ in $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots$. In other words, we have to prove that if $m_\lambda$ is written in the elementary basis of the symmetric functions, then the coefficient of $e_\mu$ is zero whenever $\mu$ is a partition of length $> e$. This should not be too hard...

Comment: OK, finishing up the proof is a standard domination argument. Consider the matrices $A = \left(a_{\mu,\nu}\right)$ and $B = \left(b_{\mu,\nu}\right)$ satisfying $e_{\mu^t} = \sum_\nu a_{\mu,\nu} m_\nu$ and $m_\mu = \sum_\nu b_{\mu,\nu} e_{\nu^t}$; these are the transfer matrices between the two bases $\left(e_{\mu^t}\right)$ and $\left(m_\mu\right)$ of the symmetric functions, and thus are mutually inverse. But it is well-known that $a_{\mu,\nu} = 0$ unless $\mu$ dominates $\nu$. This is a triangularity statement (with respect to a partial order) for the matrix $A$, and thus ...

Comment: ... also applies to its inverse matrix $B$. In other words, $b_{\mu,\nu} = 0$ unless $\mu$ dominates $\nu$. In other words, each $m_\mu$ is a linear combination of $e_{\nu^t}$ with partitions $\nu$ that are dominated by $\mu$. Applying this to $\mu = \lambda$, we conclude that $m_\lambda$ is a linear combination of $e_{\nu^t}$ with partitions $\nu$ that are dominated by $\lambda$. Each of these $\nu$ has their first entry $\leq e$ (since the first entry of $\lambda$ is $e$), and thus the corresponding $\nu^t$ have length $\leq e$, and we are done.

Comment: I forgot to say: $\mu^t$ means the transpose (aka conjugate) of the partition $\mu$. Generally, the notation is that used in arXiv:1409.8356v3, and the well-known result I am using is part of the proof of Proposition 2.17. Sorry for the messy comments where a clean answer would have been far more appropriate; my spare time is currently not in abundance :(

Comment: This is wonderful ! Thank you. If you put your comments into an answer, I will accept it.